# Will I be able to read texts written in all Romance languages simply by learning Interlingua?

Tags: conlang-learning, interlingua

Interlingua's official site claims that speakers of all Romance languages will immediately understand the language **on paper** when first exposed to it. Is this true? Can I really understand Spanish, Portuguese, Italian, Romanian, and French simply by learning a conlang?

If it is true, then why isn't it more popular?

Comment: That implies it is a subset of the Romance languages. Even if their claim is true, that doesn't mean that learning Interlingua could make you fluent in the Romance languages.

Comment: It sounds plausible for reading comprehension—already with the knowledge of Latin it is possible to get the rough contents of a text written in a Romance language, and Interlingua is closer to modern Romance than Latin. However, don't expect to get the fine points and there are notorious *false friends* than can carry you astray. Unfortunately, I have no data from serious studies, therefore only a comment.—PS: Listening comprehension or active language production are totally different things in this respect.

Comment: It sounds to me that it's the other way round: as a speaker of French or Spanish, you can understand Interlingua on paper.

Answer (score 6):

On [their site](https://www.interlingua.com/interlingua-en/) it says:

> Millions understand Interlingua "at first sight". Speakers of Romance languages especially understand Interlingua immediately and almost effortlessly. Ideal for traveling!

So it's the other way round: if you speak a Romance language, Interlingua will make sense to you because it contains many elements (eg vocabulary) from these languages. This does not, however, mean that you can necessarily understand any Romance language after learning Interlingua, though I assume there will be some benefit going both ways.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes. And also No.**
Interlingua is certainly a "simplified" Romance language and much of the lexicon is shared with other Romance languages. But not all Romance languages are made alike. Romanian is pretty divergent. Sardinian is pretty conservative. I believe Interlingua has more in common with the "central" Romance languages, standard Italian and Spanish (Castillian).

I'm sure a speaker of Italian or Castillian would have as little difficulty with Interlingua as they would have had, a couple centuries ago with Lingua Franca. I think if you were to learn Interlingua to a high degree, you would find relatively straightforward Spanish and Italian texts to be comprehensible.

Let's find out for ourselves!

---

**Interlingua**
Nostre Patre, qui es in le celos,
que tu nomine sia sanctificate;
que tu regno veni;
que tu voluntate sia facite
super le terra como etiam in le celo.
Da nos hodie nostre pan quotidian,
e pardona a nos nostre debitas
como nos pardona a nostre debitores,
e non duce nos in tentation,
sed libera nos del mal.

**Portuguese**
Pai nosso, que estás no céu,
Santificado seja o Vosso nome.
Venha a nós o Vosso reino.
Seja feita a Vossa vontade,
Assim na terra como no céu.
O pão nosso de cada dia nos dai hoje.
Perdoai as nossas ofensas
Assim como nós perdoamos a quem nos têm ofendido.
Não nos deixeis cair em tentação,
Mas livrai-nos do mal

**Mozarabic**
Padre nuoso dal ciel
sanctificadu sia al teu nomne
venga a nos al teu reynu
ed faya-se al tua voluntade
ansi en al tierra quomo en al ciel.
Al pane nuostru de cada dia da-nos-lu huoi
e perdonad-nos al nuostras offensas
quomo nos autrossi perdonamos al qui nos offended
ed non nos layšes cadere in al tentatzione
ed liberad-nos dal male

**Castillian**
Padre nuestro que estás en el Cielo,
santificado sea tu nombre,
venga a nosotros tu Reino,
hágase tu voluntad en la Tierra como en el Cielo,
danos hoy nuestro pan de cada día,
y perdona nuestras ofensas,
como también nosotros perdonamos a los que nos ofenden,
no nos dejes caer en la tentación,
y líbranos del mal.

**Catalan**
Pare nostre, que esteu en el cel,
sigui santificat el vostre nom;
vingui a nosaltres el vostre regne;
faci´s la vostra voluntat,
així en la terra com en el cel.
El nostre pa de cada dia doneu-nos avui;
i perdoneu les nostres culpes,
així com nosaltres perdonem els nostres deutors;
i no permeteu que caiguem en la temptació,
ans deslliureu-nos del mal.

**Languedocien**
Le nostre Paire që ess eïs cels 
sanctificat sia lo teus noms 
avenga lo teus regns 
et sia faita la tua voluntas 
sico ël cel è ë la tera 
è dona à nos ôi lo nostrë pa që ës sobrë causa 
è perdonna à nos lès nostrès dëoutès 
aissi co nos perdonan à nostrès dëouteïrès 
è no nos amenés en tentatio 
mes delioura nos dël mal.

**French**
Notre Père qui es aux cieux,
que ton Nom soit sanctifié,
que ton règne vienne,
que ta volonté soit faite
sur la terre comme au ciel.
Donne-nous aujourd'hui notre pain de ce jour.
Pardonne-nous nos offenses,
comme nous pardonnons aussi à ceux qui nous ont offensés.
Et ne nous soumets pas à la tentation,
mais délivre-nous du mal.

**Anglo-Norman**
Li nostre Pere, qui es ciels,
saintefiez soit li tuens uons;
avigne li tuens regnes.
Soit faite ta volonte, si comme ele est faite el ciel,
si foit ele faite en terre.
Nostre pain de chascun jor nos donne hui.
Et pardone-nos nos meffais,
si comme nos pardonons a cos qui maeffait nos ont.

**Provencal**
Paire nostre, que iest els eels; 
ton nom sia sanctifficat. 
A nos veng-a lo teu reg-nat. 
En la terra faelia sia quo el eel voluntat tia. 
Lo pa nostre cotidia liuei nos dona dieus de ta ma. 
Remet so que nos te deuem, 
quo nos als autres remetem. 
De temptacio nos deffen, 
ens delivra de mal.

**Italian**
Padre nostro che sei nei cieli,
sia santificato il tuo Nome,
venga il tuo Regno,
sia fatta la tua Volontà
come in cielo così in terra.
Dacci oggi il nostro pane quotidiano,
e rimetti a noi i nostri debiti
come noi li rimettiamo ai nostri debitori,
e non ci indurre in tentazione,
ma liberaci dal Male.

**Sicilian**
Patri nostru, ca siti nnô celu,
Fussi santificatu lu nomu vostru.
Vinissi imprescia lu regnu vostru,
Fussi faciuta la vostra Divina Vuluntati,
Comu nnô celu, d'accussì nnâ terra.
Ni dati sta jurnata lu nostru panuzzu cutiddianu,
E ni pirdunati li nostri piccati,
D'accussì niàvutri li pirdunamu ê nostri dibbitura.
E mancu ni lassati a cascari nnâ tintazzioni,
Ma ni scanzati dû mali.

**Sardinian**
Babbu nostru k’istas in sos kelos, 
santificadu siat su nòmene tou, 
benzat a nois su regnu tou 
e fatta siat sa voluntade tua 
comente in su kelu gai in sa terra. 
Su pane nostru de dogni die dàdenolu oe, 
perdona a nois sos peccados nostros 
comente nois perdonamus sos inimigos nostros, 
e non nos lesses ruer in tentatzione, 
ma lìberanos dae su male.

**Romanian**
Tatăl nostru care eşti în ceruri,
sfinţească-se numele Tău,
vie împărăţia Ta, facă-se voia ta,
precum în cer aşa şi pe pământ.
Pâinea noastră cea de toate zilele,
dă-ne-o nouă astăzi
şi ne iartă nouă greşelile noastre
precum şi noi iertăm greşiţilor noştri
şi nu ne duce pe noi în ispită
ci ne izbăveşte de cel rău.

**Classical Latin**
Pater noster, qui es in caelis;
sanctificetur nomen tuum;
adveniat regnum tuum;
fiat voluntas tua,
sicut in caelo et in terra.
Panem nostrum cotidianum da nobis hodie;
et dimitte nobis debita nostra,
sicut et nos dimittimus debitoribus nostris;
et ne nos inducas in tentationem;
sed libera nos a malo.

Comment: @DestructiveWolf - What kind of French do you speak that this one is so horribly incorrect? Anyway, this one accords with [official resources](https://eglise.catholique.fr/approfondir-sa-foi/prier/prieres/372214-notre-pere/), though does not appear to contain the "new translation" of the penultimate petition.  Do be aware that there are different dialects / forms / languages of French and quite possibly different formulations of the same prayer. I'd appreciate it if you could cite a link to the version you use, so I can review it!

Comment: Oh, didn't know that Sicilian is so different from Italian.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor - Tyranny of the National Language!  Yeah, I think most people (in the US, anyway) aren't even aware that the national languages in European countries aren't the only languages spoken in those countries. There are dozens of local languages & dialects (including some Greek) natively spoken in Italy. My plan with this answer was to present it as a kind of "language continuum"; I could easily have added scores more entries if I were to get into regional & local dialects!

Answer (score 2):

No. Of course you won’t. You don’t just learn a language by staring at it. Like everything, learning a language takes time. I would recommend learning one of those languages.